# free shipping option already set but other charged shopping option are also displayed

Tags: shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules

i have set a shopping cart rule when the sub total exceed certain amount, there will be a free shipping option let customer choose, but the strange is the charged shipping option is also displayed

[image]

Anyone know what's wrong with that?

Comment: can you share your free shipping rules screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition in following file to remove other methods if free shipping available.

```
\template\checkout\onepage\shipping_method\available.phtml
```

or you can use WebShopApps MatrixRate extension

```
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension.html
```